# What are the standard naming conventions for global objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

In Javascript, objects 'window' and 'document' start with a small letter, but global object 'Math' starts with a capital object.

Do these objects follow a standardised naming convention?

Comment: There are no standard naming conventions for JS.

Comment: How about checking this out https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml

Comment: @Niladri: That's just Google's style guide. There is no official or universal or standard style guide (despite a website with an arrogant, misleading name).

Comment: That's true , there are no universal rule though

Answer (score 1):

> In Javascript, objects 'window' and 'document' start with a small letter, but global object 'Math' starts with a capital object.

`Math` is "in JavaScript." The other two are browser-specified, not part of JavaScript.

> Do these objects follow a standardised naming convention?

The JavaScript ones do (a convention followed by the specification, that is; programmers are free to do their own thing elsewhere): Constructor functions (like `Date`) and objects whose primary purpose is to host utility functions (like `Math`) are initially-capped can CamelCase. Other functions are lower-case camelCase. `Symbol` is also capped; it creates things (symbols, which are primitives) although you don't call it via `new` (because symbols are primitives).

Browser global objects referring to specific things (like `window` and `document`) have tended to follow the lower-case camelCase convention for variables which is common in JavaScript. And browser-defined constructors like `XMLHttpRequest` have tended to match JavaScript's CamelCase for such things as well. (In both cases, I wouldn't be surprised to find exceptions; much of this stuff happened organically rather than by overall design.)

Answer (score -2):

These are all built-in JS objects. So we have to follow the conventions.

Comment: Is this a piece of the art of English language, or just nonsense ..?

Comment: @Teemu can you ellaborate your question here

Comment: As far as I can understand your answer, it's pure nonsense, but I'm not that good in English, so there might be something I haven't understood.

Comment: what do you find nonsense ? I think your English is quite good.

Comment: I think you downvoted the answer. That is fine. You can tell me the right answer to the question.

Comment: No, I didn't, because I'm not sure what it says. T.J.Crowder seems to has written the correct answer already, I've no additional information to T.J.'s answer.